# Elsevier's Computers & Security citep problem (author, year) out of bounds

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, compiling, elsarticle, harvard-style

I am trying to submit the revision of a paper to Elsevier's Computers & Security Journal. The point is that in my computer the paper compiles okay with all references in place and in the correct format but when I upload it to Elsevier's system, it doesn't.

I have tried several things but none of them did work. I first tried to upload the .bib file and invoke it using the traditional `\bibliography{}` command. But if I do so, for some reason the system does not recognise this file and when I `\citep`, the `?` symbol appears.

On the other hand, if I simply copy and paste the temporal .bbl file my computer generates directly into my main latex file, and I upload it to the system, most of the inline citations (i.e., (author, year)) go out of the text limit.

BTW, The journal requires Hardvard bibliography style and the latex template uses `\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}` for that purpose.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some differences between the TeXLive install in Elsevier's Editorial System (EES) and your local install. You can compile the manuscript on your computer and upload it as PDF, provided you zip your source files and attach them as 'LaTeX Source Files' item. EES will then simply use your PDF file for this revision round and the typsetter will sort out any issues with your source files when your manuscript is accepted.

See the [Elsevier LaTeX Instructions](http://www.elsevier.com/latex) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the late feedback. I had to submit the paper before the end of September and since nobody gave an answer by that time I did as you mentioned. So, yes, submit and the editorial system will manage it internally